# .NET service detection (If Exists?)

Tags: .net, service, servicecontroller

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I'm learning and I'm trying to use all the documentation at my disposal and I've got reasonably far, however I'm stuck on one last area.

**Problem**

I'm trying to detect if a service exists/is running and dependent on the result change a label to display the status. - I've got the status checks down, however I can't work out how to check if the service actually exists.

I'm using the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class.

**Current Sub**

```
Public Shared Sub detectExchange()

    Dim service As New ServiceController("Microsoft Exchange Service Host")

    If service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) Or service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) Then
        systemchecks.Label9.Text = "Detected - Running"

    If service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) Or service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending) Then
        systemchecks.Label9.Text = "Detected - NOT RUNNING"
    End If


End Sub
```

**My work thus far**

I've been looking for something like `Exists` I've been toying with strings like `If service.ServiceName` and `If service.` looking through all the auto-complete options but there's nothing there I can see that can detect if the service exists at all.

I have thought about using the `GetServices` method, storing it and then searching for my service name and returning the result like that?

I also tried being cheeky and simply add the below in to the status check

```
     If service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) Or service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) Then
        systemchecks.Label9.Text = "Detected - Running"
    Else
        systemchecks.Label9.Text = "NOT INSTALLED"
    End If
```

But I realise that is a terrible way of doing it and wouldn't return any value but I just wanted to see if it would return any other status.

Comment: Something exceptional happened, you expected the service to be present but it wasn't.  You deal with exceptional circumstances by using Try/Catch.  Catch the InvalidOperationException you get.  Don't catch if the absence of the service makes your program useless.

Comment: So I should change it in to a function and add a catch the exception? So in that catch I would add text to modify the label?

Comment: Sure.  Assign the label's Text property with the exception's Message property, tells the user everything he needs to know.

Comment: Thanks! I've added my answer and it works, thanks for your help Hans!

Answer (score 0):

So I added a `Try` statement as suggested in the comments, the below is my working code.

```
Public Shared Sub detectExchange()

    Dim service As New ServiceController("Microsoft Exchange Service Host")
    Try
        If service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) Or service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) Then
            systemchecks.Label9.Text = "Detected - Running"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        systemchecks.Label9.Text = "NOT INSTALLED"

    End Try

    If service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running) Or service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) Then
        systemchecks.Label9.Text = "Detected - Running"
        systemchecks.Label9.Text = "Detected - NOT RUNNING"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: No, don't do that.  Catch the *specific* exception, don't assume that the only exception you'll ever get was generated because the service was not installed.  The user might not have enough rights to use ServiceController for example.  Your message gives him no hope to figure out what the *real* problem might be.  Always use ex.Message

Comment: I'm not familiar with ex.Message - I assume that's to catch error strings? However I don't know what the error would be if it couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check if the service is already installed and get its status if exists:

```
        For Each Svc As ServiceController In ServiceController.GetServices
        Using Svc
            If Svc.ServiceName.Equals("MSExchangeServiceHost") Then 'The short name of "Microsoft Exchange Service Host"
                'The service is exist
                systemchecks.Label9.Text = Svc.Status.ToString()
                Exit For
            End If
        End Using
    Next
```